# Why am I getting a referential integrity constraint violation when trying to delete a shelf from a user in Spring Boot with H2 database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I tried deleting shelf from user but there is still a reference in the database to it and i cannot resolve it.

this is relevant code from delete controller

```
try {
    user.removeShelf(user.getShelfById(id));
    userService.save(user);
    session.setAttribute("user",user);
    shelfService.deleteShelf(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Shelf deleted successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Shelf not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("An error occurred while deleting the shelf", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
```

This is relevant code from user class, shelf doesn't have an reference to user

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class User implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<Shelf> shelfs = new HashSet<>();

 public Shelf removeShelf(Shelf shelf){
        shelfs.remove(shelf);
        return shelf;
    }
}
```

error from console

```
2023-06-03T19:10:50.988+02:00  WARN 53638 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
2023-06-03T19:10:50.988+02:00 ERROR 53638 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKGKO5TAM0R5I1GNWVA98XBX9XK: PUBLIC.USER_APLICATION_SHELFS FOREIGN KEY(SHELFS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SHELF(ID) (CAST(7 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
delete from shelf where id=? [23503-214]
2023-06-03T19:10:50.988+02:00  INFO 53638 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

It works when you create a whole new shelf and then change it, but that doesn't seem like, a proper solution